# Un-preferable investment within FSD set

Tags: statistics, economics, order-statistics

Given 3 different investments F, G and H, all of them are part of the FSD set (neither of them is superior FSD on the other).
Is there any investment H so no investor with utility function U'>0 would prefer it?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty. Consider $M(x) = \max \{ F(x), G(x), H(x) \}$. You can show that $M(x)$ is also a CDF and that $M(x)$ is **weakly FSD-dominated** by any of $F, G, H$. To play safe, shift $M(x)$ leftwards by an amount $a > 0$ and consider $M_a(x) = M(x+a)$. Now $M_a(x)$ is **strictly FSD-dominated** by any of $F, G, H$ for any $a>0$.

Comment: I don't understand how this addresses the question I want to show that there is (or not) investment that is **part of the FSD set** but no investor would prefer it, your investment is dominated by all the given set so clearly no investor would prefer it, moreover  I asked about 3 **given** investments and you created  another one.

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand your question. It said "is there any **other** investment". And "no investor would prefer it" to me means that it is FSD-dominated.

Comment: No, the **"other"** is not part of the question. also the investment H is part of the three

Comment: So you want to know whether is it possible that there is no investor with increasing utility function who would pick an investment $H$ in the FSD-set?

Comment: Basically yes, appreciate your dedication.

Comment: The answer is no. But it's a bit of a pain to write a full proof.